# How do I identify the PLL-IC clock generator chip on a HP Compaq dc5700 MicroTower Motherboard HP 0A60h

Tags: performance, motherboard, overclocking

How do I identify the PLL-IC clock generator chip on a HP Compaq dc5700 MicroTower PC
The mainboard is reports itself as an HP 0A60h. This is the most information I can get back from the motherboard with Sandra.

[Product information on HP site](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06a/12132708-12132884-12132884-12132884-12736054-12736270.html)

Comment: Chipset Intel Q965 Rev C1
Southbridge Intel 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R)

Comment: I asked someone who was selling the board on eBay to find out what was written on the chip they said: LE82Q963/SLA4X

Comment: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,1774651~root=ocusa~mode=flat~start=0#1798827

Comment: actually i think LE82Q963/SLA4X is the part number for the northbridge chipset not the PLL-IC :(

Comment: http://www.cpu-cool.de/FSB.HTM

Comment: HP part number: 404794-001

Comment: some photos i think: http://it-pifa.com/Mainboard-BTX/HP-BTX-963.htm

Comment: from the photo it looks like there is a chip with serial SLG84516S

Comment: SLG84516S datasheet for http://www.datasheetdir.com/SLG84516S+Clock-Synthesizers

Comment: another photo i think http://www.hypermicro.com/mmHM/Images/MBHP017_TOP_VIEW.JPG

Answer (score 1):

it is near to the 14.3mhz silver color oscillator.